# Permenant companion as PC

Tags: dnd-3.5e, animal-companions

I'm starting a new campaign. One player is a druid. I allowed him to have a pseudodragon as his permanent companion. Any tips on putting it on a character sheet and making this a viable character?

Comment: A bit more context please... you allowed a druid to have a Pseudodragon as an animal companion? Is there anything wrong with the regular Pseudodragon statblock from the Monster Manual?

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to the site! Take the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to how we do things around here. Your question currently reads like brainstorming, which we don't really do; in order to make it answerable, please [edit] to answer Erik's questions and provide as much detail as you can: what are you trying to *achieve* by making this companion a PC? What do you mean by "viable"? This will allow us to come up with answers that can be judged on whether or not they accomplish your goals, instead of just throwing out random ideas.

Comment: I dont know how to make it grow is the problem can it take a class of some sort etc. Im worried my player might not like that i cant figure this out what can a cat sized dragon do as a chr? Do i just tell him he has to scratch that idea?

Comment: Do you mean you've given him the Psuedodragon as his Animal Companion?  And if so, why aren't you using those progression rules?

Comment: Ive given him a pseudo as his chrs lifelong PERMENANT companion im just trying to figure out how i can make it a chr for him i liked this idea but im confused my backs to a wall i dont see how i can make this work

Comment: So far my only idea is he runs him kind of like a mini rogue but how do i make him combat viable and grow as such

Comment: Thats y i got frustrated ill get this solved somehow but idk if i can keep this idea alive he might have ro re think his chrs story and end game plans

Answer (score 1):

## Just use the Animal Companion progression rules

1. Assign the Psuedodragon an estimation penalty(established by comparing it to similarly powerful animal companions) to the effective Druid level, just like other companions.
2. Advance the companion per the rules for an Animal companion, once the Druid is high enough leveled to get the bonuses.
3. The feat Natural Bond, from Complete Adventurer, gives +3 to effective Druid level.  Allow that to mitigate the penalty, if you want to give your player additional methods of advancing the Pseudodragon.
4. Pseudodragons can wear barding and magic items.  Chain shirt barding and an animated shield will make him quite tanky, AC-wise, on top of his base natural armor.

Comment: Thanks ill read through my books and see if i dont confuse myself further if i can get this to work it will be an interesting campaign